# String.Split and Regex.Split not working?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

EDIT: A single string was missing its `(`... 8( Sorry for wasting your time.

I have a list of strings of the following format:

```
"Some Text (1234-567890)"
```

I am trying to use `string.Split` or `Regex.Split` to split this around the `(`, and then pull the preceding text from the first element, and the number text off the second element.

Ex:

```
string myText = "Some Text (1234-567890)";
string[] myValues = myText.Split('(');
string first = myValues[0]; // should hold "Some Text "
string second = myValues[1]; // should hold "1234-567890)"
```

Instead what I'm getting, and I get this whether I use `string.Split` or `Regex.Split`, is an array containing a single value without the `(`.

Ex:

```
string myText = "Some Text (1234-567890)";
string[] myValues = myText.Split('(');
string first = myValues[0]; // has "Some Text 1234-567890)"
string second = myValues[1]; // exception; there is no second value
```

This also happens if I use `Regex.Split`. Ex:

```
string[] myValues = Regex.Split(myText, "\\(");
```

If I try putting this into a fresh project, it works as I expect. The only difference between the two is that I'm populating the `List<string>` using Excel interop. I don't see why that would make a difference.

My actual code looks like this:

```
const int LOCATION_START = 2;
const int LOCATION_END = 39;
List<string> locationStrings = new List<string>();
for (int row = LOCATION_START + 1; row <= LOCATION_END; row++)
   locationStrings.Add(pExcel.ActiveSheet.ReadValue<string>(row));

List<Tuple<string, string>> locations = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
foreach (string locationString in locationStrings)
{
   string[] values = Regex.Split(locationString, "\\(");
   locations.Add(Tuple.Create(values[0].Trim(), values[1].Substring(0, 11)));
   // ^ this line throws an exception, because there is only one value, not two
}
```

`Excel.ActiveSheet.ReadValue` uses the interop Range function to read a value from an Excel sheet and casts it to a `string`.

Comment: Can you post some more details around this `List<string>` from Excel interop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you show works as expected. The only way to get that result is that the string doesn't contain any starting parenthesis, e.g. contains `"Some Text 1234-567890)"` and not `"Some Text (1234-567890)"`.

It's also possible that you have some unusal character that looks like a starting parenthesis in one environment, but is an unprintable character in another.

You should check what your strings actually contain when you get them from the Exfel sheet.

Comment: yes, you are correct. I was incorrectly concluding that the two elements were somehow fusing back into a single element. At first I thought it was LINQ flattening the enumerable for some bizarre reason. But no, you are correct, one of the values in the list was missing it's `(` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
string Source = "Some Text (1234-567890)";
string[] Splitted = Regex.Split(Source, @"\(");
foreach (string Item in Splitted)
Console.WriteLine(Item.Replace(")",""); //Use replace if you want to remove the closing bracket.
//Map the values
string First = Splitted[0];
string Second = Splitted[1].Replace(")","");
```

You need to escape the opening bracket. It has a special meaning for the regex engine.

Comment: your answer is a really long way of doing something check out my example run and test both yours and mine and what I have posted is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
string[] myValues = myText.Split(new string[] { "(" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: IWIH check the code if you run that code it still keeps a ")" in myValues[1]

Comment: @DJ KRAZE sorry for super late response, but, I didn't have laptop through that period... To exclude ")" from the text too, the code should be like this:
string[] myValues = myText.Split(new string[] { "(" , ")" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

Answer (score 0):

The data was not correctly formatted. One line was of the form:

```
"Some Text 1234-567890)"
```

and so the Split method returned just that string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this here is a solution using your code I just added a new line
    myValues[1]= myValues[1].Replace(")",""); 
this removes that annoying ")" char that you see 
**your original code works removing the "(" but there is a difference between "(" and ")"**

Here is a better example passing params separated by a **","**

```
string myText = "Some Text (1234-567890)";
string[] myValues = myText.Split('(',')');
string first = myValues[0]; // should hold "Some Text "
string second = myValues[1];
```